# Get Livewire error bag from javascript hook

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'd like to be able to get the errorBag from a livewire component within JS after receiving the `message.processed` hook. Unfortunately, the errorBag is protected so I'm a bit stuck. Does anyone know how it can be done?

This is as far as I've got

```
Livewire.hook("message.processed", (message, component) => {
    let comp = Livewire.find(component.el.getAttribute("wire:id"))
    console.log(comp.get('errorBag'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach for this.

```
public $var1, $var2, $var3;
public $errorsMessage;

protected $rules = [
   'var1' => ['required'],
   'var2' => ['required'],
   'var3' => ['required']
];

public function throwErrorBag()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(['var1' => $this->var1, 'var2' => $this->var2, 'var3' => $this->var3], $this->rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->errorsMessage = $validator->getMessageBag()->getMessages();
    }
}
```

```
<script>
   Livewire.hook("message.processed", (message, component) => {
     if (message.updateQueue[0].payload.method === 'throwErrorBag') {
        console.log(component.get('errorsMessage'))
     }
   });
</script>
```

[image]